# Inconsistent AJAX POST status 400 . Issues with image complexity

Tags: ajax, html, image, canvas, status

Our team has developed a JS HTML5 canvas based paint application. In the following code, the image data is fetched from the  canvas as base 64 encoding and posted to a servlet via ajax. The data post behaves erratically. If the image is simple , as in a straight line, I get Ajax status = 200 and the image gets saved. If the image is complex, then I get a status = 400 and the data is not saved. 
Why should the content of the POST create issues with posting of the data itself?

```
function getCode(){

 var canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 // draw cloud
  context.beginPath();

 // save canvas image as data url 
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

  // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
  // so it can be saved as an image
   document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;

  var uri= document.getElementById('canvasImg').src;


  uri = uri.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
  uri = uri.replace('=', '');

  uri = uri.trim();

 alert("uri is "+uri);

  var ajaxobject ;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    ajaxobject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject){
      ajaxobject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
     ajaxobject = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }




   ajaxobject.open("POST", "SaveImageServlet?image="+uri, true);
   ajaxobject.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   ajaxobject.onreadystatechange = function(){

   if(ajaxobject.readyState==4){
    alert(ajaxobject.status);
     if(ajaxobject.status==200){
    alert(ajaxobject.responseText);     
    }}
  };
  ajaxobject.send(null);      

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, the problem seems that you're passing the data in querystring instead of using the request body (as you should be doing since you're setting the POST verb).

Your uri should look like this:

```
SaveImageServlet
```

without the question mark and the parameter. The parameter should be set in the request body. Using jquery ajax your request would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
contentType: 'text/plain',
data: {
    "image": yourBase64string
},
dataType: 'application/json', // or whatever return dataType you want
success: function(data){
    // callback in case of success
},
error: function(){
    // callback in case of error
},
type: 'POST',
url: '/SaveImageServlet'
});
```

On server side you should be reading the data from the appropriate place. For example, if you're using .Net read it like this:

```
Request.Form["image"]
```

instead of:

```
Request.Querystring["image"]
```

This should work as intended and consistently.

Comment: Thanks , but can you let me know how its done in Javascript (without jquery)

Comment: Thanks , but can you please let me know how its done in Javascript (without jquery). In the above code of mine, I removed the appended parameters, but my servlet is throwing a nUllpointer exception.

Comment: I really don't remember how to do it in plain JS since I haven't done it in a very long time. Remember that if you use plain JS you will have to handle cross-browser by yourself. IE uses a different class than other browsers to do ajax calls. Just google for it.

Comment: I have used your code as it is, but I am unable to transmit the data. The image parameter is coming as null in the servlet. I use JAVA. Does the dataType matter?

Answer (score 0):

@Matteo, Thanks for your help and effort. However,  AJAX issue never got solved.  I found a way to send the base64 image data to the servlet. Just appended it to a hidden field and sent it as a regular form field.